# How to use scala.collection.immutable.Stream class using Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have an existing code in `Scala` and trying to write the same code in `Java`. But facing some issue.

**Scala Code**:

```
import java.io.{BufferedReader, InputStreamReader}
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.input.PortableDataStream
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

def readFile(path: String,minPartitions: Int): RDD[String] = {

      if (path.endsWith(".zip")) {
        sc.binaryFiles(path, minPartitions)
          .flatMap {
              case (name: String, content: PortableDataStream) =>
            val zis = new ZipInputStream(content.open)
            val entry = zis.getNextEntry
            val br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zis))
            Stream.continually(br.readLine()).takeWhile(_ != null)
          }
      }
    }
```

I have written below java code -

```
import org.apache.spark.input.PortableDataStream;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

        public RDD<String> readFile(String inputDir, int minPartitions) throws Exception {
    SparkSession sparkSession = null;
    sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("zipPoc").config("spark.master", "yarn").getOrCreate();

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());
    if (inputDir.endsWith(".zip")) {
        sc.binaryFiles(inputDir, minPartitions).flatMap (
            (String name , PortableDataStream content) -> {
                ZipInputStream stream = new ZipInputStream(content.open());
                ZipEntry entry = stream.getNextEntry();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                scala.collection.immutable.Stream.continually(br.readLine()).takeWhile(_ != null);
            }
        );
    }

}
```

I am getting below error.

[image]

Anyone have a clue about this and help with the appropriate code .

Comment: I'm pretty sure Java does not support `_ != null` as a shorthand for `_ -> _ != null`. No  idea why you would want to go back to Java.

Comment: I need to execute the code in AWS lambda. But AWS lambda does not support Scala.

Comment: That is lame. It should be supported.

Comment: I haven't used lambdas that much so far, but shouldn't the 5 lines starting from ZipInputStream be contained within `{}`?

Comment: First of all multi-line lambdas like the one you have there require curly braces, i.e. `() -> { //multiple lines of code here }`

Comment: Added {}. But what should I use for "Stream.continually(br.readLine()).takeWhile(_ != null)" line in Java

Comment: Searching for "AWS Lambda Scala" finds rather a lot of results saying it does, including AWS blog https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/writing-aws-lambda-functions-in-scala/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`continually` expects lambda with no parameters and returning value.
Java equivalent would be:

`() -> br.readLine()`

There is also no `_` in Java, you would have to use explicit parameter.

`(line) -> line != null`

So this should work:

```
Stream.continually(() -> {       
    try {
        return br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}).takeWhile((line) -> line != null)
```

====

As you noticed `readLine` throws checked exception. Quickest fix is just to wrap call in `try/catch`.

Comment: getting exception "unhandled exception: java.io.IOException" at br.readLine()